# Laravel 8 Livewire wire:click:prevent Not Working

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

Please Someone please I am in the middle of my final year project but this is not working I am trying for 3 days I am new so I don't know how to ask a question so if you need something please ask me Thanks
**This is the view for Shop and i have used Composer require Hardevine/shoppingcart**

[image]

**This is the ShopComponent for Shop**

[image]

Comment: first of all it is your syntax, you should be using `wire:click.prevent` instead of `wire:click:prevent` and secondly, why are you passing single quotes inside moustache `{{ }}` ? for `product->name` just pass the variable.

Answer (score 1):

When I ran `Laravel 8` on IIS, I had a similar problem. The problem was that the browser couldn't access some of the `livewire js` files, and the solution was:

Go to **`D:\Projects\Laravel\laravel8ecommerce\vendor\livewire\livewire\config\livewire.php`**
and set

```
'asset_url' => "your_url",
```

and the problem was disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. To solve this issue what I did was enclose my blade template files with a `<div>` containing an `id="main"` like so:

```html
<div id="main">
    your blade template code
<div>
```

Comment: This was the answer for my problem :D using Livewire and Laravel 9. Thanks KumTem

Answer (score 0):

Instead Of This

```
wire:click:prevent=“store({{$product->id}},’{{$product->name}}’,{{$product->regular_price}})”
```

You need to use this in your blade file

```
@livewireStyles
    your code will be in this area
@livewireScripts
```

Try This For Calling Store Function

```
wire:click.prevent="store({{$product->id}},{{$product->name}},{{$product->regular_price}})”
```

Or

```
wire:click="store({{$product->id}},{{$product->name}},{{$product->regular_price}})”
```

Comment: I have tried both ways but still its not working

Comment: And precisely what is the problem with your code?

Comment: Its wire click event is not working i think there is some version issue maybe i am following a tutorial and lot of people have faced the same issue but no one gave the solution there here is the youtube video read its comments it can help you understand the issue thanks  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pQf_zj7yKYM&list=PLz_YkiqIHesvPtvLl2Wz5FtuW44dBt199&index=7

Answer (score 0):

My solution was based on @KumTem answer

Inside the livewire blades located at app\resources\views\livewire\sample_blade.php

```
<div id="main">
... templates here
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your livewire template code should be wrapped inside a single-parent div:

```html
<div>
    <!-- Livewire Component Template-->
</div>
```